# dynamic call to a function jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, dynamic, call

I am trying to build a lib and I need to call functions dynamically depending on the variables I have in parameter like this

```
strategies = min
function dispatchRuleToStrategy(strategies)
{
    $.each(strategies, function(index, value) {
        strategy = "strategy_" + value;
    });
}

function strategy_min()
{
    // do something
}
```

How can I call the function `strategy_min()` from `dispatchRuleToStrategy()`?

I've been trying a couple of things none of which are working.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an *Object* to create a dictionary of your functions e.g. `lib`

```
var lib = {
    'strategy_min': strategy_min
};
```

then you can invoke via the key in this dictionary *Object*

```
lib['strategy_min']();
```

---

If you've named all your functions and you don't want to re-type the names over and over, you could

```
var lib = {};
function addToLib(fn) {
    lib[fn.name] = fn;
}
// then
addToLib(strategy_min);
// or
[strategy_min].forEach(addToLib);
```

Comment: hi, i've been trying to get this to work for more than an hour now but it is not. The first one with everything hard coded but when i try to do it the second way it is not working. Here is what i did `function dispatchRuleToStrategy(strategies)
{
    console.log(strategies);

    var lib = {};

    function addToLib(fn) {
        lib[fn.name] = fn;
    }
    $.each(strategies, function(index, value) {
        addToLib("strategy_" + value);
    });
}

function strategy_min()
{
    console.log("ok min");
}

function strategy_required()
{
    console.log("ok required");
}`

Comment: I've figured out what the problem is. The addToLib() cannot accept a string and I've only got a string. How can I bypass this problem ?

Comment: @khalidsookia Yes, `addToLib` expects a _function_ it is a method to add a _function_ as a property of `lib` where the name of the property is the name of the function; I was showing you alternative ways to construct the `lib` _Object_ in my second code block, the invocation method would remain `lib['strategy_min']();` as before. The advantages of using `addToLib` are simply that you don't have to hard-code your `lib` _Object_ in the same way, making it easier to update or change in future.

Answer (score 2):

Put them in an object and use the property name:

```
var strategy_table = {
    min: function() {
        // do something
    },
    max: function() {
        // do something else
    },
    ...
};
```

Then you can access them as `strategy_table[value]`:

```
$.each(strategies, function(index, value) {
    strategy_table[value]();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have already suggested to create a wrapper object for the functions, however, if your `strategy_min()` function is in the global scope, you can access it directly:

```
window['strategy_' + value]();
```

`window` in browsers refers to the global object. The bracket notation is used to access properties whose keys are dynamically generated. This way you are accessing the function, which is a property of the global object, i.e. `window`, and calling it using the parentheses.

Comment: Use of the global namespace shouldn't really be encouraged and if you rely on it to achieve this, you can't easily restructure your code to stop using it

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the real problem. I was in a jquery document ready which is a closure. I did not knew what closures were before today.

Thanks all for your help

Answer (score -3):

You can use eval() function in the following manner

```
 $.each(strategies, function(index, value) {
    strategy = "strategy_" + value;
    eval(strategy+"()");
});
```

Comment: `eval` should generally be the method of last resort.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea), amongst lots of others.

Comment: `eval` is a bad option.

Comment: One day you'll find a user that passes in `'my_evil_code(),function(){}'`